# Initialising member elements of a dynamically allocated array of structs to zero

Tags: c

I have had a look around but have not been able to find an answer to this question already. I am trying to create a hash table of which each element is a struct. In each struct is a variable to let the program know if the cell has been occupied, for this to work I need to set all of them to zero. The thing is it worked fine but now and then (seemingly randomly) I'd get an access violation. I thought I fixed it but when I come to grow my array the error creeps up again, leading me to believe that I have made an error. My pointer knowledge is not that good at all, so any help would be appreciated. This is what the function looks like:

```
HashTableCell *initialiseTable(HashTableCell *hashTable, int *tableSizePtr)
{
int i = 0;
int totalSize = *tableSizePtr * sizeof(HashTableCell);
HashTableCell *tempStartingcell;

tempStartingcell = (HashTableCell*)malloc(sizeof(HashTableCell));
*tempStartingcell = *hashTable;


while (i <= *tableSizePtr)
{
    /*we keep moving forward, need to use the first entry*/
    *hashTable = *(tempStartingcell + (i * sizeof(HashTableCell)));
    hashTable->isOccupied = 0;
    i++;
}


free(tempStartingcell);

return hashTable;
}
```

And before I malloced some space for the table and passed it in another function like so:

```
HashTableCell *hashTable;
hashTable = (HashTableCell*)malloc((sizeof(HashTableCell)*tableSize));
hashTable = initialiseTable(hashTable, tableSizePtr);
```

The idea is to start at the beginning and move along the correct number of spaces along  per iteration of the while loop. When I come to resize I merely make a new array with double the malloced space and pass it to the initialise function but this throws up an access violation error at seemingly random indexes.

I am using VS2015 if that helps anything.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What line is giving you the access violation? Have you stepped through with a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
*hashTable = *(tempStartingcell + (i * sizeof(HashTableCell)));
```

When you are adding an integer to a pointer, C and C++ already take into account the size of the array elements, so you should not multiply with sizeof(HashTableCell), but rather do:

```
*hashTable = *(tempStartingcell + i);
```

Otherwise, your extra multiplication will cause an access outside of the `tempStartingCell` array. It makes even more sense to write it like this:

```
*hashTable = tempStartingcell[i];
```

But there is more wrong with your code; if you just want to set `isOccupied` to zero for each element in `hashTable`, just do:

```
void initialiseTable(HashTableCell *hashTable, int tableSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
        hashTable[i].isOccupied = 0;
}
```

Comment: That mostly makes a lot of sense and is so much simpler, thank you.
I was wondering though, I thought to access a member of a pointer you needed the -> operator?

Comment: `hashTable[i]` is equivalent to `*(hashTable+i)`, so you don't need to dereference it again.

Comment: So in this case would hashTable[i].isOccupied and *(hashTable+i)->isOccupied be identical?

Comment: No, just `(*(hashTable+i)).isOccupied`. (I think order of operations means you need the extra parens...)